# How to make a separate function in react that fetches the data and call each time needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I want to make a function in react that get called on every component that need the data to be fetched. I tried this by the way but it returns a Promise type and not the data I need. Instead if I do console.log(res.data.user) it brings the data. Why I cannot return and have it ready to be implemented in every component I need?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import query from './queries/CurrentUser';
import receive_client from "./Client";

const CurrentUserQuery = async function () {
    const client = receive_client()
    const result = await client.query({ query: query }).then((res) => {
      return res.data.user
    })
}

export default CurrentUserQuery;
```

and here I call it

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CurrentUser from '../../CurrentUserQuery'

class Home extends Component {

  render(){

    console.log(CurrentUser())

    return(
      <div></div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't returning from your CurrentUserQuery function,

```
const CurrentUserQuery = async function () {
    const client = receive_client()
    const result = await client.query({ query: query }).then((res) => {
      return res.data.user
    })
    if(result){
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Promise object represents the eventual completion (or failure) of an asynchronous operation, and its resulting value.

In CurrentUserQuery function you should use either `await` or `then()`.

```js
const CurrentUserQuery = async function () {
  try{
    const client = receive_client()
    const response = await client.query({ query: query })
    return {success: true, user:response.data.user}
  }catch (err){
    return {success: false}
  }
}

export default CurrentUserQuery;

/* CurrentUser function return a promise. To get the resolved 
   value you have to pass a callback to 'then()' 
   which will be executed the callback once the promise is resolved.
*/
class Home extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    CurrentUser().then(({user, success}) => {
      if(success)this.setState({user})
    })
  }
   //.... Rest Of Code .....  
}
```